# If column A in file 1 = column A in file 2, replace with column B from file 2

Tags: python, linux, awk

Normally I would use R and do merge.by, but this file seems to be too big for any of the computers in the department to deal with this! (Additional info for anyone working in genetics) Essentially, imputation seems to remove the rs numbers for snp IDs, and I am left with Chromosome:Position information in its place. So I created a linkage file with all the rs numbers I want, and want to replace Chr:Pos column in file 1 with rs numbers from file 2.

So I was trying to think of a way to code:

```
If $3 of file 1 = $5 of file 2, replace $3 file 1 with $2 of file 2.
```

File 1 looks like

```
1111 1111 1:10583  G G
1112 1112 1:10583  G G
1113 1113 1:10583  G G
1114 1114 1:10583  G G
1115 1115 1:10583  G G
```

File 2 looks like

```
1   rs58108140  0   10583       1:10583
1   rs192319073 0   105830003   1:105830003
1   rs190151039 0   10583005    1:10583005
1   rs2809302   0   105830229   1:105830229
1   rs191085550 0   105830291   1:105830291
```

Desired output would be:

```
1111 1111 rs58108140  G G
1112 1112 rs58108140  G G
1113 1113 rs58108140  G G
1114 1114 rs58108140  G G
1115 1115 rs58108140  G G
```

Comment: How big file 2 could be? can You create `dict` from columns 5 and 2?

Comment: How large is each file?

Comment: If column 3 of file 1 always appears in groups ordered in the same way as column 5 of file 2, use awk and do a getline of file2 whenever you encounter a new group in file1.  Cant' provide details right now, must run.  sudo_o can give the details.

Comment: File 1 is 12.3 GB, file 2 is 410.5MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$5]=$2;next}$3 in a{$3=a[$3]}1' file2 file1
1111 1111 rs58108140 G G
1112 1112 rs58108140 G G
1113 1113 rs58108140 G G
1114 1114 rs58108140 G G
1115 1115 rs58108140 G G
```

Comment: I'm not so sure it was.. `The file seems to big` didn't sell it for me.

Comment: My computer appears to have stretched to this, and it has worked! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great. This is because we are only building an array on one column in `file2` so the array will be less than > 410.5MB which while large won't be an issue these days. As we only read `file1` line by line this isn't an issue.

Comment: The `a[$3]` condition should be `$3 in a` to avoid creating that entry if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kevin semantically it doesn't make a different as the empty value will evaluate false, but yes `$3 in a` is better.

Answer (score 0):

create dictionary from file2

```
with open('file2', 'r') as file2:
   replacement = {}
   for line in file2:
       splited_line = line.split()
       replacement[splited_line[4]] = splited_line[1]

with open('file1', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file1_new', 'w') as file1_new:
        for line in file1:
            splitted_line = line.split()
            splitted_line[2] = replacement.get(splitted_line[1], splitted_line[1])
            file1_new.write(' '.join(splitted_line)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` and `awk` can do that. You can also use `cut` instead of `awk`, but you'd have to reorder the fields afterwards in some other way.

```
join -1 3 -2 5 file1 file2 | awk '{print $2, $3, $7, $4, $5}'
```

Warning: as mentioned by sudo_O, this will work only if the files are sorted - I'm assuming they are, based on the given example. If they're not, this is not going to be very fast. If they already sorted, they will not need to be read into memory, since both commands will just process the data as it's being read.

Comment: Join requires the files to be sorted order. You don't really want to sort 2 large files, then join on them, then run through awk.

Comment: Maybe I'm assuming too much, but they do look like they're sorted in the example.

Comment: `file2` is not sorted run `diff file2 <(sort file2)
`

Comment: In the given example it is sorted by the last column, which we're trying to join on. (the command here should be `sort -k5 file2`)